# There exists an injective homomorphism of groups from $D_{2n}$ to $G$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $D_{2n}$ be a Dihedral group.

We define $G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & a^{-1} \\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b \\
a^{-1} & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$ a group.

There exists an injective homomorphism of groups from $D_{2n}$ to $G$.

If there exists as one can define a injective homomorphism. A suggestion please.

Comment: How is $G$ a group? What are $a$ and $b$? $G$ needs to be closed under products and inverses, and it is unclear why this should be the case.

Answer (score 0):

There exists an injective group homomorphism for only $n=1$.and not for any other value of n.Since your $G$ is isomorphic to $Z_2$

Comment: Why only for $n=1$

Comment: Because then the domain has only two elements.and if you need an injective homomorphism this means you should have a subgroup like(isomorphic) the domain in your codomain. Then as for all n greater than 1 you will have the order of the domain more than the codomain.and in that case your G can't contain it since G has only two elements